# Has anyone been able to integrate liquidhaskell with nixos?

Tags: haskell, nixos, liquid-haskell

I'm trying to use liquidhaskell on NixOS.  I can install the package (liquidhaskell-0.8.2.3), though not the cabal integration, because it requires cabal 1.18-1.25, but I have cabal 2.0.1.0 .

I have installed the liquidhaskell package as part of a ghc-with-packages setup:

```
[~:0]$ readlink $( type -p liquid )
/nix/store/pdbzl0p6k1klmajx969b6vvwyw9w0s6b-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages/bin/liquid
```

Among many others, the package text also installed in this set:

```
[proclib:1]$ ls -ld /nix/store/pdbzl0p6k1klmajx969b6vvwyw9w0s6b-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages/lib/ghc-8.2.2/text-1.2.2.2/
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 68 Jan  1  1970 /nix/store/pdbzl0p6k1klmajx969b6vvwyw9w0s6b-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages/lib/ghc-8.2.2/text-1.2.2.2/
```

However, liquid cannot see this:

```
[proclib:1]$ liquid ~/bin/h/nix.hs 
LiquidHaskell Version 0.8.2.3
Copyright 2013-18 Regents of the University of California. All Rights Reserved.

liquid: Main: Could not find module ‘Data.Text’
Perhaps you meant Data.Set (from containers-0.5.10.2)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

The above is not part of a cabal package (to try to eliminate the cabal thing from the equation).

I've tried playing with nix-shell to make this work, but either nix-shell or liquid break down on language pragmas:

```
[~:0]$ nix-shell -p myHaskellEnv --run liquid ~/bin/h/nix.hs 
/nix/store/q1cwqhb6v8yx8vy4s5p6sxrq8s0bnqmy-nix.hs: line 5: {-#: command not found
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: The last error is actually from bash trying to run your haskell sources as though it were a shell script. Quoting the command should fix that: `--run "liquid ~/bin/h/nix.hs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that liquid haskell ignores the ghcWithPackages wrappers, because it uses the GHC API directly. You can work around this as follows, based on [this thread](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/issues/1099#issuecomment-332012128).

```
nix-shell -p 'haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages(pkgs:[pkgs.text (pkgs.liquidhaskell)])' -p z3 --run 'liquid --ghc-option="-package-db=$(ghc-pkg list | head -n 1)" ./hellotext.hs'
```

Or somewhat equivalently,

```
nix-shell -p 'haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages(pkgs:[pkgs.text])' -p z3 -p haskellPackages.liquidhaskell --run 'NIX_GHC_LIBDIR=$(ghc-pkg list | head -n 1)/.. liquid ./hellotext.hs'
```

which suggests that it will work out of the box when you're in a `nix-shell` based on a `cabal2nix` package.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That seems to work.  As a side note, the use with a cabal2nix package isn't working for me, because NIX_GHC_LIBDIR isn't being set - something seems to have changed there.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't expect that, but it should work on the current unstable channel though: `cd someproject; nix-shell -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/cc4677c36ee8d880e881459ad114fd2224b3ac1c.tar.gz --run 'echo NIX_GHC_LIBDIR is $NIX_GHC_LIBDIR'`

Comment: cheers.  Actually, it wasn't the channel that was at fault; I had a rogue shell.nix; I was trynig to fix my default.nix, but blanking that i had a shell.nix that was breaking me.